# Items in the list become copy of last item added

Tags: python, data-structures

I recently started learning python and ran into the problem. I want to create a list with several different instances of the "Value" class:

```
class Value:
    x = []
    y = []

data1 = Value
data1.x = 1, 2
data1.y = 2, 3

data2 = Value
data2.x = 3, 4
data2.y = 4, 5
```

But when I add these elements to the list, there are 2 elements I need in the list, but for some reason the first element is a copy of the second, i.e. the fields of the first become x == 3, 4 and y == 4, 5 like those of the second:

```
answer.append(data1) // answer[0].x == 1, 2    answer[0].y == 3, 4
answer.append(data2) // answer[0].x == 3, 4    answer[0].y == 4, 5
```

What do i need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: You created class variables, not instance variables. Instance variables are created in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems. With `data1 = Value` you just give the class `Value` an additional name `data1`. To create an instance of the class you have to do `data1 = Value()`.

But now the next problem arises. You define `x` and `y` as attributes of the class and both values are empty lists. Then with `data1.x = 1, 2` you create an instance attribute which is a `tuple` and has nothing to do with the class attribute of the same name. Now when you try to append something to `x` it won't work.

```
class Value:
    x = []

data1 = Value()
data1.x = 1, 2
data1.x.append(4)
```

This will lead to the error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`.

Don't recreate mutable attributes from the outside (or at least use the same data type as before). Use the attributes methods to alter it.

```
class Value:
    x = []

data1 = Value()
data1.x.extend((1, 2))
data1.x.append(4)
print(data1.x)
```

This will give you `[1, 2, 4]`.

The result looks good, but it isn't. Let's add a second instance.

```
class Value:
    x = []

data1 = Value()
data1.x.extend((1, 2))
data1.x.append(4)
print(data1.x)

data2 = Value()
data2.x.append(5)

print(data1.x)
print(data2.x)
```

The result is `[1, 2, 4, 5]` for `data1.x` and `data2.x`. But why?

I mentioned before that you created class atrributes. The class attributes share their value over all instances. If you want an instance attribute you have to define it on the instance. When you create an instance of a class the `__init__` method will be called and that's where you have to create the attributes.

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []

data1 = Value()
data1.x.extend((1, 2))
data1.x.append(4)
print(data1.x)

data2 = Value()
data2.x.append(5)

print(data1.x)
print(data2.x)
```

Now we get `[1, 2, 4]` and `[5]` as expected.

Adding the second attribute `y` should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

its fairly simple actually
when you write:

```
data1 = Value 
data2 = Value
```

you are referencing the class instead of creating an instance.
By writing:

```
data1.x = 1, 2
data1.y = 2, 3
```

you are now changing the actual value of your class and not the value of an instance.
So when you do the following:

```
data2.x = 3, 4
data2.y = 4, 5
```

you are changing the class Value and **not** an **instance** of Value.
Which you can easily check by printing:

```
print(Value.x)
print(Value.y)
```

so writing

```
data1 = Value
data2 = Value
```

is the same as writing:

```
data1 = data2 = Value
```

you want to use:

```
data1 = Value()
data2 = Value()
```

to create to different **instances** of your class which you can modify individually.

Answer (score -1):

you should use classes as follows

```
class Value:
    x = []
    y = []


data1 = Value()
data1.x = 1, 2
data1.y = 2, 3

data2 = Value()
data2.x = 3, 4
data2.y = 4, 5
```